# Flutter webview package

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm working on an app that contains the webview_flutter package and every time I try to add this package then run the app for a tasting I get this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':webview_flutter'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':webview_flutter:classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-3.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-3.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.0/builder-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find sdklib-26.3.0.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:26.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/26.3.0/sdklib-26.3.0.jar
   > Could not find bundletool-0.6.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.6.0/bundletool-0.6.0.jar
   > Could not find protos-26.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/26.3.0/protos-26.3.0.jar
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':webview_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to rebuild the project many times and tried some other versions of Gradle and none of this worked.. 
can anyone help, please?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `flutter clean` in your console. This should wipe anything that may be stopping your app from running.

Comment: it removes all packages then i use pub get then i get the same message